# Website Protection- Am i doing it right?

Tags: php, security, encryption, password-protection, password-encryption

I have some doubts about my security in my website, And i was wondering if I'm doing it correctly or not.

for POST\GET requests i always use `mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$2nd_parametter);`

for Password Encryption i use `password_hash('$password', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('salt' == 9));`

> People told me that BCRYPT is better than SHA for Website passwords.

for Login validation i use `if($username === $db_username && $password === $db_password){};`

for Pages accessibility check i use

```
if($_SESSION['role'] == 'Admin'){header("Location: admin");}}
    else{header("Location: index");}
```

for Database connection  `mysqli_connect(localhost,root,,'database');`

> I do realize that this connection is vulnerable since there is no
>   password

I would like to know if there is any better way to do these protection steps effectively and easily and even making it way stronger.

Comment: I recommend you to ask on [Security @ SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/), because it specializes on questions like this (about web application hardening).

Comment: @AntonSamsonov Didn't know about this part, I'll check it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. mysqli_real_escape_string()**

The escaping function is meant to insert user input into SQL-queries, not for usage in GET/POST requests. There is a *better and more comfortable* way though, you can use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), to protect from SQL-injection. To escape user input for HTML, the function `htmlspecialchars()` is better suited.

**2. password_hash()**

The password_hash() function should indeed be used, though it would be safer and more future proof to write it like this:

```
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Your cost factor is a bit low and with `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` the algorithm could be changed in future should this be necessary.

**3. if($username === $db_username && $password === $db_password)**

This is actually not possible if you really used the password_hash() function, because of the random salt. Instead you have to check the password with:

```
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $db_password);
```

**4. if($_SESSION['role'] == 'Admin'){header("Location: admin");}}**

Redirecting to protected pages is unsafe, nobody prevents an attacker to call the page directly. Each page has to check the permission on its own, if the logged in user should not see the page, then you can show the password form.

Answer (score 0):

try this type

```
$input = "Yourpasswordtext";

$encrypted = encryptionIt( $input );
$decrypted = decryptionIt( $encrypted );

echo $encrypted . '<br />' . $decrypted;

function encryptionIt( $q ) {
    $key  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $encodestring      = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $key ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $key ) ) ) );
    return( $encodestring );
}

function decryptionIt( $q ) {
    $key  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $decodestring      = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $key ), base64_decode( $q ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $key ) ) ), "\0");
    return( $decodestring );
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that the OP encrypt his passwords instead of hash them or did you just not read the question?  This code is also insecure for standard use anyway.